# Django Two Many to one fields in entity

Tags: django, many-to-one

Following [django doc for many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), they has the situation:

```
  class Reporter(models.Model):
    ...

  class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
    ...
```

If I need get all Articles from Reporter, I could do: reporter.article_set.all(). So far, so good.

But, imagine that the Article need have a Auxiliary Reporter (reporter_aux).

```
class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, related_name='reporter')
    reporter_aux = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, related_name='reporter_aux')
    ...
```

How I could get all the articles that a reporter was auxiliary (from reporter_aux)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to edit your related name to somthing else; for example

```
article_reporter_aux
```

you can do a Django reverse lookup for the related_name

```
reporter.article_reporter_aux.all()
```